# How to query sub subdocument using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

let say i have a schema like this:

```
const Product = mongoose.schema({
   product_id: uuid,
   product_quantity: number,
})
const Customer = mongoose.schema({
   customer_id: uuid,
   customer_cart: [product],
})
const Store = mongoose.schema({
   store_id: string,
   customers: [customer],
})
```

how can I query the product if i have the store_id ,customer_id and the product_id?
I know i can query it by get back all store document and use loop to loop through the object array.
But i think it will be very slow if the store have many customer and customer have many product in their cart.

Is there a way to just get back the product without get back the whole store document?

Comment: You don't have to create multiple nested documents, individual collections would be better and also need not to create the id fields, it will be created by default and you can store the id reference only in each model. Do you want to create multiple store? what is your purpose please elaborate?

Comment: @PritthishNath what i want is that when a customer add a product in their cart in a specific store, I will get the store id, customer id and the product id. I want to use the information to query the customer cart and modify the quantity of that product.

Comment: Do you have a separate Product collection? you should create a separate Product collection first, then add product reference and quantity in cart array.